# How to stop screen video recording programmatically in Swift - Flutter?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, screen, recording

I want to stop the ongoing screen recording in iOS which user has started using the Control Center. For stopping the recording, the user would click on a button inside Flutter app. Tried using ReplayKit to stop screen recording, as below code:

**Environment:** Flutter v2.10.5

**Challenges faced:**
Tested on Simulator and an iPhone, the `isScreenRecording` bool works, but the stop recording doesn't seem to work.

Any thing wrong here? Or can ReplayKit stop ongoing global recording started from Control Center.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```swift
import UIKit
import Flutter
import MoEngage
import moengage_flutter
import flutter_downloader
import AVFoundation
import Foundation
import ReplayKit

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        }
        
        var moSDKConfig : MOSDKConfig
        
        let moAppId = ""
        
        if let config = MoEngage.sharedInstance().getDefaultSDKConfiguration() {
            moSDKConfig = config
            moSDKConfig.moeAppID = moAppId
        } else {
            moSDKConfig = MOSDKConfig.init(appID: moAppId)
        }
        
        moSDKConfig.appGroupID = "group.com.package-name.shared"
        moSDKConfig.moeDataCenter = DATA_CENTER_01
        
        MOFlutterInitializer.sharedInstance.initializeWithSDKConfig(
            moSDKConfig,
            andLaunchOptions: launchOptions
        )
        
        FlutterDownloaderPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback(registerPlugins)
        
        let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        
        let isMicrophoneAvailable = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "package-name/audio_recorder",
                                                         binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
        isMicrophoneAvailable.setMethodCallHandler({
            [weak self] (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult) -> Void in
            guard call.method == "isMicrophoneAvailable" else {
                result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
                return
            }
            self?.isMicrophoneAvailable(result: result)
        })

        let screenRecording = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "package-name/screen_recording",
                                                         binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)

        screenRecording.setMethodCallHandler({
            [weak self] (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
            switch call.method {
            case "stop_screen_share", "is_screen_share_active":
                self?.screenRecordActions(call, result)
            default:
                result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
            }
        })
        
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

        // Set your desired minimumBackgroundFetchInterval
        let backgroundIntervalInMinutes = 60
        UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(TimeInterval(60*backgroundIntervalInMinutes))

        
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    
    private func isMicrophoneAvailable(result: FlutterResult) {
        if AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().isOtherAudioPlaying == false {
            result(Bool(true))
        } else {
            result(Bool(false))
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Screen Record
    
    private func screenRecordActions(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, _ result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
        switch call.method {
        case "stop_screen_share":
             RPScreenRecorder.shared().stopCapture( handler: { (error) in
                print("stopping recording");
            })
            
        case "is_screen_share_active":
            let isRecording = RPScreenRecorder.shared().isRecording;
            result(isRecording)
        default:
            print("Not Valid")
        }
    }
}

private func registerPlugins(registry: FlutterPluginRegistry) {
    if (!registry.hasPlugin("FlutterDownloaderPlugin")) {
        FlutterDownloaderPlugin.register(with: registry.registrar(forPlugin: "FlutterDownloaderPlugin")!)
    }
}
```

**content_protection.dart**

```dart
part of '../app_extension.dart';

class QContentProtection {
  QContentProtection._();
  static const platform = MethodChannel('package-name/screen_recording');

  final SecureContent _secureContent = SecureContent();

  void preventScreenshotAndroid(bool prevent) {
    _secureContent.preventScreenshotAndroid(prevent);
  }

  // Future<void> startRecording() async {
  //   try {
  //     await platform.invokeMethod('start_screen_share');
  //   } catch (e, s) {
  //     log('[QContentProtection.startRecording] error : $e, $s');
  //     QAppX.extendedRouter.showNotificationsShade(
  //       message: e.toString(),
  //       type: QInAppNotificationType.failure,
  //     );
  //   }
  // }

  Future<void> stopRecording() async {
    try {
      await platform.invokeMethod('stop_screen_share');
    } catch (e, s) {
      log('[QContentProtection.stopRecording] error : $e, $s');
      QAppX.extendedRouter.showNotificationsShade(
        message: e.toString(),
        type: QInAppNotificationType.failure,
      );
    }
  }

  Future<bool> isScreenRecordingOn() async {
    try {
      final isScreenRecordingOn = await platform.invokeMethod<bool>('is_screen_share_active');
      log('[QContentProtection.isScreenRecordingOn] isScreenRecordingOn : $isScreenRecordingOn');
      return isScreenRecordingOn ?? false;
    } catch (e, s) {
      log('[QContentProtection.isScreenRecordingOn] error : $e, $s');
      QAppX.extendedRouter.showNotificationsShade(
        message: e.toString(),
        type: QInAppNotificationType.failure,
      );
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

```dart
onPressed: () {
    final isScreenRecordingOn = await QAppX.contentProtection.isScreenRecordingOn();
    if (isScreenRecordingOn) {
        QAppX.contentProtection.stopRecording();
    }
}
```